# Avalonia SaveFileDialog freezes app, but OpenFileDialog works fine

Tags: c#, avaloniaui, avalonia

I'm trying to open a `SaveFileDialog` from a ReactiveCommand in Avalonia.

```
public ReactiveCommand<Window, Unit> SaveFileAs { get; } = ReactiveCommand.Create((Window source) =>
{
    var path = new SaveFileDialog().ShowAsync(source).Result;
    // ...
});
```

The code above freezes as the dialog is closed. However, the `OpenFileDialog` works as expected.

```
public ReactiveCommand<Window, Unit> OpenFile { get; } = ReactiveCommand.Create((Window source) =>
{
    var paths = new OpenFileDialog().ShowAsync(source).Result;
    // ...
});
```

I also have applied `[STAThread]` to the main method (by default from the Avalonia MVVM template).

```
// Program.cs
[STAThread]
public static void Main(string[] args) => BuildAvaloniaApp()
    .StartWithClassicDesktopLifetime(args);
```

What is the cause for this peculiar behavior? What is the fix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think freezing in your code is caused by `Result`. Try to switch to `async/await` for both dialogs:

```
var dlg = new SaveFileDialog();
var result = await dlg.ShowAsync(this);
```

You'll probably need to use `CreateFromTask()` instead of sync `Create()`.